# setContextPath() not found

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the library [Porcupine](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine) on Android. I have now downloaded a Rhino context file (.rhn) but can't find a way how to implement that file into my code.

The [documentation](https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/picovoice-android/) says that I should use `setContextPath()` but this gives me the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setContextPath' in 'Builder'

That's how I tried it:

```java
try {
    porcupineManager = new PorcupineManager.Builder()
            .setModelPath("porcupine_params_de.pv")
            .setAccessKey(ACCESS_KEY)
            .setKeywordPath("my_file_de_android_v2_0_0.ppn")
            .setContextPath("my_file_de_android_v2_0_0.rhn");
            .setSensitivity(0.7f).build(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    porcupineManagerCallback);
    porcupineManager.start();
}
...
```

I don't know what this method is good for since I can't even find it in its [class](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/blob/master/binding/android/Porcupine/porcupine/src/main/java/ai/picovoice/porcupine/PorcupineManager.java).

So how can I use my .rhn file?

Comment: Mighty be better to start with the Android demo, which doesn't use that builder method.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have tried that already but unfortunately, the demo is not using any .rhn files. So I couldn't find `setContextPath()` in the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code from the link you provide, this method is called on different class:

```
PicovoiceManager picovoiceManager = new PicovoiceManager.Builder()
  .setAccessKey("${ACCESS_KEY}")
  .setKeywordPath("${KEYWORD_FILE_PATH}")
  .setWakeWordCallback(wakeWordCallback)
  .setContextPath("${CONTEXT_FILE_PATH}")
  .setInferenceCallback(inferenceCallback)
  .build(context);
```

you use `PorcupineManager` while sample code uses `PicovoiceManager`.

Comment: Thanks! But I am not able to use the class `PicovoiceManager`. I have tried to import it with `import ai.picovoice.picovoice.*;` but I get the error _Cannot resolve symbol 'picovoice'_. So the second `picovoice` doesn't exist.

Comment: @xRay have you added dependency? : implementation 'ai.picovoice:picovoice-android:2.0.0'. On their github : https://github.com/Picovoice/picovoice it looks like version 2.0.0 is the current one. On this page you can also find short sample code for initialization : https://github.com/Picovoice/picovoice#android

Comment: Yes, I was already using `ai.picovoice:porcupine-android:2.0.0` but not `ai.picovoice:picovoice-android:1.1.0`. I have implemented it and now it works. Thanks for this advice!